# jQuery fancybox changes opacity and gets darker when I click on a link

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, fancybox

```
$(".various").fancybox({
    maxWidth    : 500,
    maxHeight   : 800,
    fitToView   : false,
    width       : '60%',
    height      : '100%',
    autoSize    : false,
    openEffect  : 'none',
    closeEffect : 'none',
});

<table>

<?php
    while( $row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
    {
       echo "<tr><td><a href='edit.php?id=".$row['pat_id']."' class='various fancybox.ajax'>Edit Product</a></td></tr>"
    }

</table>
```

I've done paging here, fancybox works fine when i'm on first page. When i goto someother page and click on EditProduct, background gets darker, on further clicks it keeps on getting dark and requires more clicks to get back to normal. I've searched a lot but hasn't find any solutions. Any help please

Comment: I think its keep on opening the new popup on each click. So its appearing to be of darker color each time. And Same while closing it takes multiple times to close each one.

Comment: Maybe but then why it works fine on 20 records on first page?

Comment: Ok. Is there any other way to link fancybox to records coming from database. Thanks:)

Comment: make sure that function $(".various").fancybox() is not in any kind of loop

Comment: @Sumit Its in script section of page

Comment: My mistake. Didn't read your post to the end. Make a console.log after your $(".various").fancybox() to look for a loop. I think you reinit it on every page-change.

Comment: is `$(".various").fancybox()` wrapped in a `$(document).ready()` method ?

Comment: Additionally, the `echo` construct should be closed with a semi-colon `;`  ... also your `<?php` is not properly closed, is it just a typo ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your "parent" page "A" (the page which has the code you are mentioning) you have loaded the fancybox, as you said in the "script" (i guess you mean the head section) section.

So far, no problem, everything looks ok.

The problem is in the page "B" that you are trying to load using ajax. **If i'm guessing correctly, that page "B" IS ALSO loading fancybox in ITS "script" (head) section.**

So fancybox re-initiates through ajax-loaded "B" page while some magic has already happened from parent page "A" initiation and that is causing the "nested" behaviour.

**Solution: Do not load fancybox again in your ajax page**

*My very specific guess in your problem:*

Is page "A" and "B" the same page (edit.php)?

If the page loads another instance of itself, let's say edit.php tries to load edit.php in a different "mode" you can load it like:

```
echo "<tr><td><a href='edit.php?id=".$row['pat_id']."&mode=DISABLE_LOADING_OF_SCRIPTS' class='various fancybox.ajax'>Edit Product</a></td></tr>"
```

...and then of course do a check in your edit.php head section...

```
<head>
<?php if($_POST['mode']!='DISABLE_LOADING_OF_SCRIPTS') { ?>
<script type="text/javascript">

......loading/initiation of fancybox here.......

</script>
<?php } ?>
```

...so scripts are loaded only in your "main" version of edit.php where you populate the data.

if that's the case, i also think that is a bad idea to use your edit.php to do all the work. It's difficult to debug, difficult to follow the flow of your program. Create a "producteditor.php" to do the editing work, and keep your edit.php just for viewing your dataset.